# for thread unknowing behavior

Tags: c#, for-loop, task

Look at this code:

```
foreach (string t in tar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Program.CountAccount; i++) {
        Program.log("Лайк " + t);
        int ind = i;
        ts[ind] = new Task(delegate {
        MessageBox.Show(
            //cooks[Index]
            Program.browsers[ind].CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://m.ok.ru/")).Count.ToString(), "count");
        Program.browsers[ind].Liking(t);
    }); ts[ind].Start();
```

The cookie is empty, if I not use int `IND`.

Why i need to use `IND`? Without it logic breaks (cookie in my browser is empty in new thread), I met this bug a lot of times, solution is to use an additional variable, but can you tell me, what I'm doing wrong, why `for(i[0-N])` can't access static object `MyClient browsers[i]`?

Comment: Please add a language tag (is it [tag:c#]?)

Comment: Someone is doing liking  bot? )))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp